# toogle in jquery, change divs but if statement not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

im working on this, im trying to show 1 div at the time but i cant make the divs change to show only 1 option:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#boton1").click(function () {
        $('#tdecredito').Toggle("slow");
    });
    $("#boton3").click(function () {
        $('#tdecredito').Toggle("slow");
    });
    $("#boton2").click(function () {
        $('#deposito').Toggle("slow");
    });
    $("#boton4").click(function () {
        $('#deposito').Toggle("slow");
    });

    var isVisible = $( "#tdecredito" ).is( ":visible" );
    var isHidden = $( "#tdecredito" ).is( ":hidden" );
    var isVisibleb = $( "#deposito" ).is( ":visibleb" );
    var isHiddenb = $( "#deposito" ).is( ":hiddenb" );

    if($('#tdecredito').is(":visible")) 
    {
        $('#deposito').hide(":hiddenb"); 
    } 
    else($('#deposito').is(":visibleb")) 
    {
        $('#tdecredito').hide(":hidden"); 
    }     
});
```

test page:[Test page](http://www.chileansoftware.cl/cambiaso/prueba/newbook.asp)

Comment: `Toggle()` should be `toggle()`, and what is `$( "#deposito" ).is( ":visibleb" );` supposed to be doing?

Comment: first, thanks for the quick reply :) . the function is the two divs show it by toggle 1 at time and if the user want to "change" by pressig "x" button changes to the other div, i read here in the forums about "visible" and "hidden" but dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need 4 buttons and why you need the is visible part. Here is one solution http://jsfiddle.net/x3FCx/2/.

Simply start with one hidden element, and as you click buttons, both of the divs get toggled, meaning, the one who is visible gets hidden and the one who is hidden gets visible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#boton1").click(function () {
    $('#tdecredito').toggle("slow");
    $('#deposito').toggle("slow");
});
$("#boton3").click(function () {
    $('#tdecredito').toggle("slow");
    $('#deposito').toggle("slow");
});
$("#boton2").click(function () {
    $('#tdecredito').toggle("slow");
    $('#deposito').toggle("slow");
});
$("#boton4").click(function () {
    $('#tdecredito').toggle("slow");
    $('#deposito').toggle("slow");
});

$('#deposito').hide();
```

});

Comment: works like a charm! if you see "x" button its like "close" but changes the toogle div. Thanks for the reply and help!